# How do you access just the specific index of a Vector of Objects?

Tags: c++, vector, indexing

everyone! I am writing a program where I have a Vector of 10 Class Objects. I am attempting to use various sorts (selection, insertion and bubble) to organize the data in the Vector.

The problem is, the class objects have several member variables (strings, ints and doubles), and I'm having difficulty referencing just the index number in my code.

Here's an example:

```
void selectionSort(vector<Student> & vStudents, int size)
{
int index;
int smallestIndex;
int location;
int temp;

for (index = 0; index < size - 1; index++)
{
    smallestIndex = index;

    for (location = index + 1; location < size; location++)
        if (vStudents[location] < vStudents[smallestIndex])
            smallestIndex = location;

    temp = vStudents[smallestIndex];
}
}
```

My goal here is to track the index and move the index position around, but I'm getting errors about data type conversion from "Student" (the class data type) and "int" (the index I'm trying to track). I have accessors and mutators, and the goal is eventually to sort the data by last name (one of the member variables), and I haven't even gotten to that yet because I'm having my initial problem (though any help with that as well would be amazing lol).

I'd hoped that this may help others, as I've actually had a hard time tracking down exactly how to do this online. I know you're all Coding Wizards, and I very much appreciate you taking the time to even look!

Thank you very much ahead of time,
Maeric

Comment: `temp` is an `int` and `vStudents[smallestIndex]` is of type `Student`, so unless you provide some kind of type-casting function it is (`temp = vStudents[smallestIndex];`) not going to work.

Comment: I don't understand what the inner for loop is trying to achieve. In order for `temp` to be able to assigned to `vStudents[smallestIndex]` it must be of type `Student`. So `Student temp`, would work however I'm not sure that the inner for loop is going to do what you want perhaps you will need to use the dot  operator to access some value of student `vStudents[location].(someProperty)`

Comment: Thank you for your responses! You're right, Jonas, it certainly isn't going to work as is. And thank you for your input, cogle. To be perfectly honest, I'm not entirely aware of what the inner loop is doing either. I copied this code (supposedly the typical "selection sort" layout) from my teacher's online materials. He has it written out just like this for an array, and it's been my job to somehow convert it for a vector of objects lol. It's been... challenging to say the least -_-